# Why can't I swap characters in a javascript string?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to swap first and last characters of array.But javascript is not letting me swap. 
I don't want to use any built in function.

```
function swap(arr, first, last){
    var temp = arr[first];    
    arr[first] = arr[last];
    arr[last] = temp;
}
```

Comment: You're going to have to use a built-in function. JavaScript might implicitly call the String constructor for you if you concatenate the old string with an empty string but there's no way to do it without using a built in function.

Answer (score 26):

Because strings are immutable.

The array notation is just that: a notation, a shortcut of `charAt` method. You can use it to get characters by position, but not to set them.

So if you want to change some characters, you must split the string into parts, and build the desired new string from them:

```
function swapStr(str, first, last){
    return str.substr(0, first)
           + str[last]
           + str.substring(first+1, last)
           + str[first]
           + str.substr(last+1);
}
```

Alternatively, you can convert the string to an array:

```
function swapStr(str, first, last){
    var arr = str.split('');
    swap(arr, first, last); // Your swap function
    return arr.join('');
}
```

Comment: Please note that the `split` method plays total havoc with multi-byte unicode characters used by some languages.

Comment: @JeremyJStarcher do you have more info about that?

Comment: Play with some of the multibyte examples here:  https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-unicode

Comment: @DavidDiez If you care about this, you can use `var arr = [...str]` instead of `split`.

Comment: Thank you @Oriol! I like more your second approach; I think it's more robust, although I'm not sure if it is as efficient as the first solution (I think it is). The first solution doesn't handle the case when start and end indices are the same.

Comment: @Oriol I prefer the alternate solution. I have seen that splitting and concatenating strings is quite slow if the string is long; also, it would be infeasible with respect to running time if the string needs to be rearranged a lot, say n! (n factorial) times. Converting the string first is much better and can also allow arbitrary swaps. Thanks so much, it really helped!

Comment: this won't work if the first and last are the same, it won't work if the last is the end index, it's a bad solution, please add the edge cases

Answer (score 3):

Let me offer my side of what I understood: swapping items of an array could be something like:

```
var myFish = ["angel", "clown", "mandarin", "surgeon"];
var popped = myFish.pop();
myFish.unshift(popped) // results in ["surgeon", "angel", "clown", "mandarin"]
```

Regarding swaping first and last letters of an strings could be done using **Regular Expression** using something like:

```
"mandarin".replace(/^(\w)(.*)(\w)$/,"$3$2$1")// outputs nandarim ==> m is last character and n is first letter
```

Answer (score 2):

I just ran your code right out of Chrome, and it seemed to work find for me.  Make sure the indices you pass in for "first" and "last" are correct (remember JavaScript is 0-index based).  You might want to also try using console.log in order to print out certain variables and debug if it still doesn't work for you.

EDIT: I didn't realize you were trying to manipulate a String; I thought you just meant an array of characters or values.

[image: My code]

Answer (score 1):

```
function swapStr(str, first, last) {
    if (first == last) {
      return str;
    }

    if (last < first) {
      var temp = last;
      last = first;
      first = temp;
    }

    if (first >= str.length) {
      return str;

    }
    return str.substring(0, first) +
      str[last] +

      str.substring(first + 1, last) +

      str[first] +
      str.substring(last + 1);
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Swap characters inside a string requires the string to convert into an array, then the array can be converted into string again:

```
function swap(arr, first, last){
    arr = arr.split('');    //to array
    var temp = arr[first];    
    arr[first] = arr[last];
    arr[last] = temp;
    arr = arr.join("").toString()    //to string
    return arr;
}
```

Following usage:

```
str = "ABCDE"
str = swap(str,1,2)
console.log(str)     //print "ACBDE"
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this piece of code will help somebody.

```
var word =  "DED MOROZ";

var arr = word.split('');

for (var i = 0; i < arr.length/2; i++) {

   var temp = arr[i];

   arr[i] = arr[arr.length - i - 1];

   arr[word.length - i - 1] =  temp;
}

console.log(arr.join(""));
```

Run this code and your characters will be swapped.